# Is this an entropy identity?

Tags: probability, statistics, information-theory, entropy

For $\mathcal{X}$ finite, take $\mathcal{X}$-valued random variables $x_1,\dots, x_n$ with some joint distribution and a function $f:\mathcal{X}^n\to \mathbb{N}^n$. Also choose $I$ uniformly randomly from $1$ to $n$. Is it true that
$$\frac{1}{n}H(f(x_1,\dots,x_n))= H(f(x_1,\dots, x_n)| I, (x_t)_{t\neq I})
?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition we have 
\begin{equation}
H(f(X_1,...,X_n)| I , X_1,..., X_{I-1},X_{I+1},...,X_n) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= \sum_{i \in [n]} \frac{1}{n} H(f(X_1,...,X_n) |  X_1,..., X_{i-1},X_{i+1},...,X_n)
\end{equation}
and therefore the identity is true iff \begin{equation}
H(f(X_1,...,X_n)) = \sum_{i \in [n]} H(f(X_1,...,X_n) |  X_1,..., X_{i-1},X_{i+1},...,X_n)
\end{equation}
which is very unlikely to be true.

**Dependent Counter-example**

Consider the case $f = \text{id}$ then this is equivalent to 
 \begin{equation}
\sum_{i \in [n]}H(X_i |X_1,...,X_{i-1}) = \sum_{i \in [n]} H(X_i)
\end{equation}
and if the $X_i$ are not independent then 
 \begin{equation}
\sum_{i \in [n]}H(X_i |X_1,...,X_{i-1}) < \sum_{i \in [n]} H(X_i),
\end{equation}
because they will have non-zero [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).

**Independent Counter-example**

The counterexample when the $X_i$ are independent is a bit less trivial. Suppose the $X_i$ are i.i.d. uniformly random binary (i.e. nice and fair coin flips) and let $f(X_1,...,X_n) = X_1+...+X_n$ then we have that 
\begin{equation}
H(f(X_1,...,X_n))  = - \sum_{k \in [n]} \binom{n}{k} 2^{-n} \log \left(\binom{n}{k} 2^{-n}  \right) 
\end{equation}
  and 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i \in [n]} H(f(X_1,...,X_n) |  X_1,..., X_{i-1},X_{i+1},...,X_n) 
\end{equation}
 \begin{equation}
=  \sum_{i \in [n]} H(X_1+...+X_n |  X_1,..., X_{i-1},X_{i+1},...,X_n) =  \sum_{i \in [n]} H(X_i) = n
\end{equation}
which are not equal since
\begin{equation}
- \sum_{k \in [n]} \binom{n}{k} 2^{-n} \log \left(\binom{n}{k} 2^{-n}  \right) = \mathcal{O} \left( \log n \right)
\end{equation}
since it takes  $\mathcal{O} \left( \log n \right)$ bits to describe the range $X_1+...+X_n \in \left[1,2,...,\binom{n+1}{2}\right] $.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the counterexamples. If you are interested, see my comment in the other answer, I think under (much) more stringent conditions such a statement can be true.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on your definition of level sets? I am a bit confused about that.

Comment: The $z$-level set of $f$ is the following subset of the domain: $\{(x_t)_t: f((x_t)_t)=z\}$

Comment: Sorry lol I meant "what is your def of simple functions?" Sorry I was a bit sleepy.

Comment: By $f$ simple I mean that each of its level sets has the form $s_1\times \dots \times s_n \subset \mathcal{X}\times \dots\times \mathcal{X}$ with each $s_t \subset \mathcal{X}$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the setting, here is an obvious counterexample:

Let $f$ be the identity function. Since there are no restrictions on the joint probability distribution, let $P(x_1 = x_2 = ... = x_n) = 1$ So, for all outcomes where at least one of the random variables attains a different value the probability is zero.

Then, even conditioning on one of the random variables yields a zero entropy because the vector becomes deterministic. So, for all such joint distributions where there is more than one outcome with positive probability,

$H(x_1,...,x_n | I, \{x_i\}_{i \neq I}) = 0 \neq \frac{1}{n} H(x_1,...,x_n)$

Comment: Yep, IDK how I didn't see it, thanks. All my counterexamples had the RVs independent, though to me it still seems likely that doesn't fix it. I'll form a new question

Comment: The issue is, the right hand side (RHS) is random, while the left handside (LHS) is not. For example, assuming they are independent, you can have the rv.s to be uniform over different supports. Then, the outcome of $I$ essentially picks one of the supports, say $A \subseteq \mathcal{X}$ and we get $RHS = \log(|A|)$. So, you should instead think about an expected entropy on the RHS. Even then, I think you can stick to my example of uniform distributions over different supports and come up with a smart function and a smart set of support sizes to break the equality

Comment: Alright, I think it might be true when the $(x_t)_t$ are independent and $f$ is simple, that is, level sets of $f$ are of the form $s_1\times \dots \times s_n,\ s_t\subset \mathcal{X}.$ That way many things seem to combine nicely expanding the LHS.